# How to connect Mongo DB with Angular Dart?

Tags: mongodb, angular-dart

I am using `mongo_dart 0.3.1`. Can anyone help me to connect **MongoDB** to Angular DART application?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you've tried, what problems you've run into, etc.?

Comment: Actually, I am new in Dart and I am trying the example of hero App tutorial on the dart. Now I am trying to connect my app with database and I like to use MongoDB. I have installed mongo_dart. Now I do not have any Idea how to import and connect the DB and use in web application mean Angular dar. It will be great help if you could give me an example app with mongoBD like a simple form submit data to DB and show the data in a page. Thanks in advance.

Comment: MongoDB doesn't run in the browser, therefore you can't connect to it from Angular. I don't know MongoDB, it might have some HTTP API that you can connect to, if not, you need to build your own server that exposes some HTTP API to the internet and translates requests to Mongo-DB commands/queries. This is in no way related to Dart or Angular, only to code that is run in the browser.

Comment: If this is a "browser" target or do you actually realize this should be a "server" target? Perhaps you should show what you have actually tried so far. Otherwise, then you want what actually just got submitted in response seconds before.

Comment: I like to build a web application that will interact with Database. Like web application with node js + MongoDB. Or PHP, MYSQL,HTML. But I do not know how to work with a database(mongoDB) in Dart.